# Files do not update after restoring disk from disk image

Tags: linux, bash, mount

I have an extended partition with two partitions : P_SYSTEM (1 Gb ) and P_RESTORE ( 2 Gb ). In P_RESTORE  I have an image of P_SYSTEM at one point in time. Once both of these partitions mounted with the mount command :

```
mount  /dev/sda7 /home/myPartitions/P_SYSTEM
mount  /dev/sda9 /home/myPartitions/P_RESTORE
```

I restore P_SYSTEM with :

```
dd if=/home/myPartitions/P_RECOVERY/system.img of=/dev/sda7
```

The recovery works but I need to unmount/mount the P_SYSTEM evry time to see changes made to my directory. I tried the sync command but it didn't work (no changes in directory). I tried :

```
sudo sync /dev/sda7
```

and

```
sudo sync /home/myPartitions/P_SYSTEM
```

Is there a command to update my directory without mount/unmounting?

Also these 1 and 2 Gb partitions are only tests I'll be working on bigger ones later.

Comment: No! Please don't do that. You'll trash your filesystems

Comment: I mentioned the sync command because I tried it and it was discussed on other similar topics. I can't seem to find something similar to mount/unmounting to see the result of my disk image restoration though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands make the filesystems active on your system:

> ```
> mount  /dev/sda7 /home/myPartitions/P_SYSTEM
> mount  /dev/sda9 /home/myPartitions/P_RESTORE
> ```

This command could be used to overwrite an *inactive* disk partition that might contain a filesystem. It *must not* be used to overwrite a mounted filesystem:

> ```
> dd if=/home/myPartitions/P_RECOVERY/system.img of=/dev/sda7
> ```

If you do this you will almost certainly end up with a corrupted filesystem on your target. It will also take forever and a day because you're using `dd` without any optimisations.

**↑ DO NOT DO THAT ↑**

Instead, you need to restore the image while the target filesystem is unmounted:

```
umount /dev/sda7     # The partition holding P_SYSTEM
mount /dev/sda9 /home/myPartitions/P_RESTORE

cat /home/myPartitions/P_RESTORE/system.img >/dev/sda7
fsck -f /dev/sda7    # In case the system.img file was created from a live filesystem
```

Now you can mount the restored `P_SYSTEM` filesystem once more

```
mount /dev/sda7 /home/myPartitions/P_SYSTEM
```